# Proper use of athwart

Tags: word-usage

I have researched on the word "Athwart", but I'm still unsure how to use it correctly. Can I use it like "Across"?

For example : "I looked at the window athwart the room."?

Comment: My advice, don't use it. Ever. It's far too obscure. Why use a word hardly anybody knows ?

Comment: When you dress up as Cap'n Ahab for Hallowe'en you can say it.

Comment: +1 for taking an interest in obscure English words. You made me smile.

Comment: It's not obscure. It's specialized. Not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

athwart is a sailing term, most of all.

Athwart, athwartships
At right angles to the fore and aft or centerline of a ship. Athwart, athwartships

It's the kind of term you will find in novels by:

You might try the BOOKS of Patrick O'Brian for instance:

Patrick O'Brian (given name: Richard Patrick Russ, 1914 - 2000) was the author of twenty books (and three chapters) detailing the naval and terrestrial exploits of Captain Jack Aubrey and Doctor Stephen Maturin, in a period from 1801 to 1815.

http://www.patrickobrian.com/